# Why is my client not hearing the socket io event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I don't understand why my event handler isnt firing for the userOffline event. My other events are working fine...

Below I will post my code.

Here's my server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('messageFromServer');
  socket.on('messageToServer', (dataFromClient) => {
    connectedUsers[dataFromClient.username] = socket;
  });
  socket.on('join', ({ username, room }) => {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.emit('message', 'Welcome!');
    socket.broadcast
      .to(room)
      .emit('message', `${username} has joined the room!`);
  });
  socket.on('messageRoom', ({ username, room, message }) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', `${username}: ${message}`);
  });
  socket.on('call', ({ username, id }) => {
    if (connectedUsers[username]) {
      connectedUsers[username].emit('recieveCall', id);
      console.log('online emitted');
    } else {
      socket.emit('userOffline');
      console.log('offline emitted');
    }
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.disconnect(true);
  });
});
```

client:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import StateContext from '../StateContext';
import DispatchContext from '../DispatchContext';
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:5000';

const Socket = () => {
  const appState = useContext(StateContext);
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('messageFromServer', () => {
      socket.emit('messageToServer', { username: appState.username });
    });
    socket.on('mailNotification', () => {
      document.getElementById('notifyMail').classList.add('notify');
    });
    socket.on('boardsNotification', () => {
      document.getElementById('notifyBoards').classList.add('notify');
    });
    socket.on('userOffline', () => {
      console.log('user offline');
      appDispatch({
        type: 'flashMessage',
        value: 'User is offline',
        fmType: 'danger',
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default Socket;
```

nb: the call event is fired by a different react component.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: You set `connectedUsers[dataFromClient.username] = socket;` and i can't find where you set it to undefined/null/false, so `if (connectedUsers[username]) {` is always true and the code `socket.emit('userOffline');` is never reached

Comment: it's null until they come online. I'm getting the console.log running but not the event handler and have no clue why...